# Unmarshal JSON into Golang type Big.Float

Tags: json, go

I have a json message that needs to be unmarshaled to a struct which has some `big.Float` fields from the `math` package. The json field is of type numeric. It gives me `err = json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type *big.Float`.

I wonder why it complains "cannot unmarshal string" since my json field is numeric type. And what do I need to do to unmarshal the json filed to a `*big.Float` field.

Example:

```
type Msg struct {  
      Usage0   *big.Float 
      Usage1   *big.Float 
      Usage2   *big.Float       
}

// jsonMsg = {'Usage0': 31241.4543, "Usage1": 54354325423.65, ...}

err := json.Unmarshal(jsonMsg, &msg)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It appears to me (based on the docs) that it expects the json for `big.Float` to be passed in as strings.  This play proves that to work:

https://play.golang.org/p/7XKn2hhXRD

If you cannot control the json then you can implement your own unmarshaller as an alternative.

Comment: So the message is meant to be retrieved from a message queue (Kestrel). We just need to keep precise enough numbers so we used big.Float. In order to keep the precision in the message queue, should we use json's string or numeric type when writing to the queue in another upstream program?